# .XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[53088,40] Message: The reference to entity "T" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamreader

I have got receive an xml inputstream with a URLConnection. However when i try to unmarshall the inputstream. It throw an exception.
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

- with linked exception:
  [javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[53088,40]
  Message: The reference to entity "T" must end with the ';' delimiter.]

CODE:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(hostURL);  
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();  
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authDetails);

    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    xif.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing", true); 
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);

     // Advance to the "Packages" element.
     while(xsr.hasNext()) {
         if(xsr.isStartElement() && "packages".equals(xsr.getLocalName())) {
             break;
         }
         xsr.next();
      }
     
     JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Packages.class);
     Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
     packages = (Packages) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
    }catch (JAXBException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     }finally{

    }
```

PS: [row,col]:[53088,40] = newproductsite for T&T evol

You can find Stack traces in link http://pastebin.com/LuhbnMQq

Comment: Surely it is obvious that it is the linked exception that is important, not the outer exception?

Answer (score 1):

Your XML file isn't well-formed.

```
newproductsite for T&T evol
```

You cannot have a '&' in the XML file, it must be represented as

```
&amp;
```

How was the XML produced? The error is there...

Comment: infact the xml is a response from URLconnection request to a server and cannt be modified i need to escape the special character but dont know how to

Comment: Confront the ones responsible for the server application that answers your request with the error message and that line [53088,40], adding the surrounding lines so that they can see the complete XML element. It would be interesting to hear their answer.

Comment: It would also be interesting to try without `xif.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing", true);` and see whether the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml input is not well formed. In the text `newproductsite for T&T evol` the ampersand is a reserved character. It is used for escaping (e.g. `&lt;` represents the `<` sign or `&#x41;` is the letter `A`. So, after the `&` in the text, the parser expects a value and a `;` to see that the escape sequence is finished.
If you want to use the ampersand in your xml elements, it must be escaped e.g. by `&amp;`.

To fix the problem the source needs to produce either well-formed xml or you need to sanitize the data you received before processing it. I would recommend the first.

Comment: Sanitize XML that is or isn't really XML? Please explain how to do this *reliably*.

Comment: infact the xml is a response from URLconnection request to a server and cannt be modified i need to escape the special character but dont know how to

Comment: @laune: It can't be done reliably for all cases, but maybe reliably enough to help the original poster with the problem. If non-escaped ampersands are the only problem with the xml, simply replacing `&` with `&amp;` could help.

Comment: So what if there is a `&lt;` in some text node? Or a '&' inside a CDATA?